# Is there a standard size for images with text and its thumbnails?

Tags: images, website-design, design, thumbnail, image-size

I have a main question and a secondary one. I'm creating images with text on them and I'm designing the website where the images will be shared on but I'm concerned about the size of the main image and its thumbnail.

**Q:** Is there any standard size for images with text?
My actual size for the images is 850x400, here's the example:

[image: 850x400]

**Q:** If you think the size (850x400) is correct, then what would be the best size for a thumbnail? 
I have thought of thumbnail of the size of 493x232 (which is 58% of the original size 850x400) and it looks like this:

[image: 493x232]

I want the main image and the thumbnail to be indexed by Google like the same image but different sizes and I want the thumbnail to be easy to read for the users! Any help will be so much appreciated, once I settle for sure what the size of the main image and its thumbnail will be I can proceed with the design of my website.

PS. I'm planning on having Google ads on the website (in case you consider the dimension of the ads to be potential image sizes)

PS. Anything related to SEO interest me a lot. Thank you!

Comment: "standard size for images with text?" - I'm struggling to even imagine what kind of "standard" this might be?! Whatever size is chosen is surely dependent on the context, the text (size and quantity) and devices this is intended to be viewed on? It's your call. Google won't have any trouble indexing images of this size, or any other size for that matter.

Comment: @w3dk Thank you for your interest in my question! Since there would be a lot of images in my website I will create images with little text and images almost full of text. But I cannot create images with different dimensions! I was just tying to pick one size and stick with if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any standard size for images with text? ... what would be the best size for a thumbnail? ... I want the main image and the thumbnail to be indexed by Google like the same image but different sizes and I want the thumbnail to be easy to read for the users!

You should try and get an idea of what devices your users use so that you can choose the right size image based on the device.

Visit google analytics and add the tracking code they supply to you to your site and in a few days or so, you will be able to see what screen resolutions your users use. There's a good chance someone will use a low screen resolution to visit your site, and a big image size you presented will not be readable by such a small device.

Here's what I suggest.

For the large image, make two versions.

One would be for mobile devices and a maximum width of 240 pixels should be enough to cater to every mobile device in existence.

One would cater to desktop and laptop computers. Try to aim for the computer with the oldest setup. I think that would be 640 pixels in width maximum.

If you're doing only plain text as images for thumbnails, then you're better off doing ordinary links with anchor tags. The bandwidth requirement will be less and the text can also be resized to match user's preferences (via web browser settings).

If you insist on actual image thumbnails, I can't recommend a specific size because you have to think about the site and why the thumbnail size is right. For example, if you were doing a color chooser, a thumbnail could be a solid color thats only maybe a few pixels wide and a few pixels high. If you're doing a fancy title selector, then each thumbnail could be several pixels long by a few pixels high to fit the one-line text.

If you want the images indexed individually, then give each one a specific width, height, and alt tag, but make sure the width and height match the actual width and height of the image. Make sure the contents of the alt tag accurately describe the image.

Comment: thank you a lot for your answer! The website doesn't exist, yet but I'll consider what you have told me. I think making two versions of the same image will be wise, one for mobile devices and another one for desktop with oldest setup.